# What should be the Big O of f(n) = n^5 + 2^log(n)?

Tags: math, big-o, logarithm

I came across a problem where I've to select the correct Big O for the function **f(n) = n^5 + 2^log(n)**...
I tried putting large values and found out that n^5 grows significantly as compare to 2^log(n)... But then someone told me that exponential functions grow significantly as compared to other functions... And I got confused again... To be honest I think 2^log(n) is not an exponential function... But because of my weak logarithmic concepts, I am unable to prove that...

> I just want someone to tell me that yes n^5 is larger than 2^log(n) so that I can prove that 2^log(n) is not an exponential function...

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O(2<sup>logn</sup>)=O(n) - this follows straight from the definition of logarithm.

More formally:

f(n)=2<sup>logn</sup>

log<sub>2</sub>f(n)=log<sub>2</sub>(2<sup>logn</sup>)=lognlog<sub>2</sub>2=log<sub>2</sub>n
==>f(n)=n

==> O(2<sup>logn</sup>)=O(n)

==> O(n<sup>5</sup> + 2<sup>logn</sup>)=O(n<sup>5</sup> + n)=O(n<sup>5</sup>)

Comment: Thanks a lot... Just a confirmation.. 2^log(n) = n right?

Comment: yes, in the context of complexity. Out of complexity scope, log should have base 2 to make it right

Comment: Actually, as correctly pointed out by @MarkDickinson below, for any base > 2, 2^logn > n, but that shouldn't matter for your final result

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername `for any base > 2, 2^logn > n` Guess you meant `2^logn < n`.

Answer (score 1):

`2^log(n) = (2/e)^log(n) * e^log(n) = a^log(n) * n` where `a = 2/e < 1` (assuming `log` is the natural logarithm).

It follows that `f(n) = n^5 + 2^log(n) < n^5 + n` and therefore `f(n) = O(n^5)`.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   In the general case of logarithms of an arbitrary base `b`, using that `2 = b^log_b(2)` it follows that:

```
    2^log_b(n) = (b^log_b(2))^(log_b(n))
               = b^(log_b(2)*log_b(n))
               = (b^log_b(n))^log_b(2)
               = n^log_b(2)
               = n^(1/log_2(b))
```

Therefore `f(n) = n^5 + log_b(n) = O( n^5 + n^(1/log_2(b)) ) = O( n^max(5, 1/log_2(b)) )`.

In particular, `f(n) = O(n^5)` for `log_2(b) > 1/5  ⇔  b > 2^(1/5)`, which covers the common `log` bases of `2`, `e`, `10`.

Comment: The assumption that log is the natural algorithm is both incorrect and irrelevant. When talking about complexity the base is irrelevant and any base can be assumed for the sake of computation. Specifically here base 2 (which is the usual base in cs-related topics) immediately results in 2^logn = n.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername In a situation like this where the log is in an exponent, the base of the logarithm *does* matter for the purposes of complexity analysis. For example, `10^log10(n)` is `n`, but `10^log2(n)` is approximately `n^3.3`. The first of these is `O(n)`; the second is not. In this *particular* example we happen to get the same answer whether the base is 2, 10 or e, but in general the base is not irrelevant.

Comment: @MarkDickinson You're right, of course. I should've been more precise - my intention was just to point out that O(logn) is the same for any constant base.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername The base of the logarithm *is* relevant in exponentials of the form `a^log_b(n)` (though `2` and `e` happen to yield the same end answer in this particular example). As to what the base is assumed to be here, only the OP can clarify that. With a `math` tag on a programming site like SO, assuming natural logarithms is, well, natural since that's what `log` means by default in mathematica, javascript, c++ etc.

Comment: @dxiv Natural logarithm is never assumed unless stated explicitly in complexity analysis in cs. It's either not important, or assumed to be 2 or stated explicitly where it matters.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername It is a fair assumption the OP may be solving a complexity exercise, but it's just that, an assumption. There is no mention of complexity in either the question or the tags, and asymptotic behaviors are not limited to complexity analysis.